# FastAPI main not executed

Tags: python, program-entry-point, rest, execution, fastapi

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import person

app = FastAPI()

local_database = []

@app.get('/')
def index():
    """Return the todo"""
    return "Use: URL/docs to access API documentation"

@app.get('/people')
def get_people():
    if not local_database:    
        return 'Database empty'
    
    people_info = [person for person in local_database]
    return people_info

@app.post('/people')
def create_person(person: person.Person):
    local_database.append(person)
    return 'Added new person to database'

@app.get("/people/{person_id}")
def read_all_infos(person_id: int):
    try:
        return local_database[person_id]
    except IndexError as e:
        return repr(e)
        # This is much better than any str()-like solutions, because it actually includes the type of exception.
        
@app.get("/people/information/salary")
def read_salary(name: str, gender: str, age: int, password: str):    
    
    for pers in local_database:
        if (    pers.name == name 
            and pers.gender == gender 
            and password == "123456"
            ):
            return pers.salary
    
    return 'Could not find your person'

@app.get("/people/information/gender")
def read_gender(name: str):
    print(name)
    for pers in local_database:
        if pers.name == name:
            return pers

    return 'Could not find your person'

# maybe needed
def populate_database():
    dummy_person1 = person.Person(salary = 55000, gender="male", name ="Jack", age = 22)
    dummy_person2 = person.Person(salary = 120000, gender="female", name ="Rose", age = 42)
    local_database.append(dummy_person1)    
    local_database.append(dummy_person2)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    populate_database()
```

My goal is to use FastAPI to communicate with a local in-memory database for testing purposes. However, in my main I'd like to run `populate_database()` to add some instances of the class Person to the list.

Then I want to use a HTTP request GET to receive the local_data.
Unfortunately the `local_database` list is not populated. I would expect 2 instances of Person inside the database.
Any idea why the local_database list is not populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the module is run from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt its `__name__` is being set as `"__main__"`. [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Effectively, `populate_database` is only executed when you're running it via `python <filename>` but you're probably running it using `uvicorn` or another runner which executes it as a normal module.

Try moving `populate_database` call outside the `if __name__ = "__main__"` guard.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for the fast reply.